# How can I make part of base_url in codeigniter as a dynamic one?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My base_url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/VI';
```

This is one of my image link:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/footer.png')?>">
```

its work fine. My need is, 
**footer.png** is an image I need to take this image name from database.

And it is possible through this:

`http://localhost/VI/assets/images/<?php echo $footer->image;?>`
 And this is working fine for me.

Now I need to know that there is any method to include   `<?php echo $footer->image;?>` in

`<?php echo base_url('assets/images/footer.png')?>` instead of `footer.png`.

Comment: Have a slash at the end of `base_url()` as [docs say](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L10). Like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/VI/';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should include the footer image dynamically inside your code:

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/images/' . $footer->image); ?>
```

The dot operator concatenates two strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$footer->image` in base_url as

```
<?php echo base_url("assets/images/".$footer->image)?>
```

You can add `base_url()` in image tag as

```
<?php echo img(array('src'=>base_url().'assets/images/'.$footer->image, 'alt'=> $footer->image)); ?>
```